# RegEx for no whitespace at the beginning and end but allows all special characters , spaces , lowercase and uppercase alphabet and numbers in between

Tags: javascript, angular, regex

I wanted to design an regex for not allowing whitespace at the beginning and at the end of a string, but allows all special characters , spaces , lowercase and uppercase alphabets and numbers in between

The regex I tried is :

```
'^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$'
```

I am using it as a pattern validator inside input in angular as : `pattern ="^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$'"`

anyhelp would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `string.trim()` will remove whitespace on both ends

Comment: Is there a min or max length as well?

Comment: Hi , I am not using it inside Javascript , I am using it as a pattern validator inside input in angular as : pattern ="^[A-Za-z0-9 _]*[A-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9 _]*$'"

Comment: Try: `^\S.*\S$` (min length 2)

Comment: Thanks Anubhava , I will try it out and let you know if it is working

Comment: Do you also allow single char inputs?

Answer (score 1):

You need either

```js
Validators.pattern('\\S(?:.*\\S)?')
```

Or

```js
Validators.pattern(/^\S(?:.*\S)?$/)
```

In both cases, the regex is `^\S(?:.*\S)?$` and matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\S` - any char other than whitespace
- `(?:.*\S)?` - an optional occurrence of any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then a non-whitespace char
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 1):

All the ASCII alphabets and special characters are defined with `[!-\[\]-~]`

By making sure the first and optional last is this class is all that's needed.

`^[!-\[\]-~]+(?:[^\S\r\n]*[!-\[\]-~])*$`

https://regex101.com/r/JpsOvy/1

```
 ^ 
 [!-\[\]-~]+ 
 (?: [^\S\r\n]* [!-\[\]-~] )*
 $
```

`[^\S\r\n]` is just non-linefeed white space. Replace with `\s` if needed.